# QGIS 2.14 Couldn't load PyQGIS. No module named Qsci

Tags: qgis, python, installation, windows

When I open QGIS Version 2.14 Essen, I get the following error message:

```
Couldn't load PyQGIS.
Python support will be disabled.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\gui\__init__.py", line 26, in 
    from qgis._gui import *
ImportError: No module named Qsci
Python version:
2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

QGIS version:
2.14.0-Essen 'Essen', 98e9610

Python path:
['C:/PROGRA~2/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python.
...
...
...
```

Comment: My guess is that the installation was broken somehow. I experienced something like this a while ago with installing QGIS 2.8 standalone. I remedied it by removing and then reinstalling it using the OSGeo4W Network Installer. Can't confirm if this would work in your situation for QGIS 2.14 though =)